# Windows service does not start auto in azure Virtual Machine Scale Set instance

Tags: azure, windows-services, azure-vm-scale-set

Windows service does not start automatically due to logon failure in the Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set instance. It is showing an incorrect username or password error in Event Viewer. But it can be started manually with the same credentials. The startup type of the service is Automatic and Log on As an Account Credential. It does not have dependencies.

Comment: Try changing the service's "Startup type" value to "Automatic (Delayed Start)" and see if that helps: https://superuser.com/a/285655/54909

Answer (score 1):

We stopped an automatic service in our environment (VMSS instance) and restarted the server and then we can see the service is getting started automatically without any logon failure.

**Before server restart:**

[image]

**After server restart**

[image]

With respect to your error, there might be an issue with your log on account permission. This behavior may occur if one or more of the following conditions are true:

- The password is changed on the account with which the service is configured to log on
- The password data in the registry is damaged.
- The right to log on as a service is revoked for the specified user account.

Please check the below official document to troubleshoot the issue.

[Troubleshoot service startup permissions - Windows Server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/system-management-components/service-startup-permissions)